# workflow to send Single mail for multiple items modified

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have an approve button on a page and a list. More than one list items are approved by clicking on this approve button. Now If I create a workflow to mail the specific person, it will send him mail many times(equal to the total number of items approved).

How to make the workflow to send only one mail, what condition has to be given?

Comment: You can create a new list and create a column called "Status" in that. You can then hook up a workflow to this list to run on creation or modification. On button click, when every item has changed, you can update the status in that and that way, only 1 mail would be sent.

Comment: What part of the above solution didn't work? After approving all items, you can update the status of the new list. If workflow is set to run on item updation, it will surely run.

Comment: what has to be done so that after updating multiple rows of status column in first list, it will update only one row of status column other list?